# linux-firmware apt package VS fwupd tool: Are they doing same thing?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, firmware

I noticed here two things about firmware:

### 1. apt list linux-firmware

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware

```
$ apt list linux-firmware -a
Listing... Done
linux-firmware/focal-updates,focal-updates 1.187.17 all [upgradable from: 1.187.16]
linux-firmware/now 1.187.16 all [installed,upgradable to: 1.187.17]
linux-firmware/focal,focal 1.187 all
```

### 2. fwupdmgr

https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Fwupd
https://github.com/fwupd/fwupd
https://fwupd.org/lvfs/docs/users

```
$ fwupdmgr get-updates 
Devices with no available firmware updates: 
 • KIOXIA-EXCERIA PLUS SSD
 • UEFI Device Firmware
 • UEFI Device Firmware
 • UEFI dbx
Devices with the latest available firmware version:
 • Thunderbolt host controller
 • Embedded Controller
 • Prometheus
 • System Firmware
 • UEFI Device Firmware
No updates available for remaining devices
```

```
$ fwupdmgr get-releases 
Choose a device:
0.  Cancel
1.  0dc2af238bee6aba3964d974a6ca6e967f3d78fb (Thunderbolt host controller)
2.  d4db94d2324ae6986698e7489b234c0377fd8465 (Embedded Controller)
3.  d432baa2162a32c1554ef24bd8281953b9d07c11 (Prometheus)
4.  09647b198775f1868cc695ec2685477e0964c323 (System Firmware)
5.  317fd9ef3f069f67047ab1163f8c040c3853cc38 (UEFI Device Firmware)
```

---

Are they doing (install/update firmware) the same thing (from different update source) ?

Answer (score 0):

Through a period of use and exploration, I got this conclusion.
// feelings and summaries, Not 100% sure

---

People may confuse `fwupd` with `linux-firmware` package:

- `fwupd` tool manage firmware which will flash to peripheral SoC when you do update/flash.
- `linux-firmware` package update blob which will load to peripheral SoC RAM at every system boot